# Python substrate-interface discovering which params need to be passed into query function for parallel API?

Tags: python, substrateinterface

I am trying to find the correct parameters to pass into the query function for the substrate interface module when interacting with the parallel api to interact with their AMM. I attempted to modify the code from the linked post:

[How to determine which parameters are required when using substrate.query() to query a storage_function from polkascan's py-substrate-interface?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/107/how-to-determine-which-parameters-are-required-when-using-substrate-query-to-q)

Below is my adapted code:

```python
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface

paraurl = 'wss://rpc.parallel.fi'

substrate = SubstrateInterface(
    url=paraurl,
)

storage_function = substrate.get_metadata_storage_function('AMM','Pools')

typeString = storage_function.get_params_type_string()
print('Storage Function params length:', len(typeString))


# Retrieve a SCALE object of the param type
param_type = substrate.create_scale_object(storage_function.get_params_type_string()[0])

# Possible options of Enum type
print(param_type.type_mapping)

token_param = substrate.create_scale_object(param_type.type_mapping[0][1])

# Show possible options
print(token_param.type_mapping)
```

However, I am receiving the error:

```
  File "/home/travnado300/Documents/Python Scripts/Substrate Interactions/Parallel.py", line 30, in <module>
    token_param = substrate.create_scale_object(param_type.type_mapping[0][1])
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am wondering if this is just an issue with the parallel API not having all of the information available or if there is a way to access the params needed to pass into the function:

```
substrate.query()
```

Comment: You can check it manually with the [PolkadotJS website](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.parallel.fi#/chainstate). Or do you really need to figure this out dynamically?

Comment: Can i check the required parameters there? I would like the code to be dynamic to pull the query on its own, but i do not need to check the parameters dynamically.

Comment: Did you check the link? You can select `Amm::pools` there and see the signature of `(u32, u32) -> Option<PalletTraitsPool>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `storage_function.get_param_info()` to get more information about the param types:

```python
storage_function = substrate.get_metadata_storage_function('AMM', 'Pools')

param_info = storage_function.get_param_info()

print(param_info)
# [{'primitive': 'u32'}, {'primitive': 'u32'}]
```

More information see: https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#type-information-about-how-to-format-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are missing a step here, before using `param_type`. Possibly a `decode()` after `create_scale_object`, similar to https://github.com/polkascan/py-scale-codec/blob/master/README.md#encode-a-call